# Caesar cipher in Haskell. " parse error on input '=' "

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a caesar cipher in Haskell. When I run this code I get a " parse error on input '=' ". What should be changed? I'm loading this up from a source file (Sublime) into ghci.

```
import Data.Char


let2int :: Char -> Int
let2int c = ord c - ord 'a'

int2let :: Int -> Char
int2let n = chr (ord 'a' + n)

shift :: Int -> Char -> Char
shift n c
 | isLower c = int2let ((let2int c + n) `mod` 26)
 | otherwise = c

 encode :: Int -> String -> String
 encode n xs = [shift n x | x <- xs]
```

Comment: the code is fine and works when I try it - how to you *run the code*?

Comment: navigate to the directory and then :l filename

Comment: You might get better help if you include the full error message.

Comment: You're probably running the code in GHCi or similar. GHCi works in the IO monad, so for every = binding you'll have to use `let name = body`. When trying more than one function it's best if you write them in a file and then load it in the interpreter with the `:load` command.

Comment: Did you save your last changes? Maybe you are trying to load an older version?

Comment: Most particularly, including the *line number* would help.

Comment: Is your code in the file indented exactly as you've posted? That is, are all lines except the `|` guards unindented?

Answer (score 3):

`encode` doesn't start at the same position as the other top-level definitions. Remove the extra space.

Comment: This fixed it, can't believe I missed that whitespace. Thank you!